# Angular 2 Forms Required Field Validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am performing required field validation on angular 2 input fields.
On Chrome I see a tooltip when I pass my mouse over the field "Please fill out this field" and radio buttons I see "Please select one of these options" but on edge and IE I do not see anything....and over that I am also not able to see any color difference or comment though I added the below code. Please help me resolve this.

In CSS

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm form-group">
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" required #name="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
<div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
Name is a Required Field</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an sample to recreate your problem. For example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: That tooltip is not an angular thing. It's controlled by the browser anytime you add "required" to a field. Though, in Angular, if you enclose your input in a form tag (which you should be doing anyway), you shouldn't see that popup anymore. If you're going to use tooltips though, it's best to just override them with your own custom ones. They're easy to make and help with browser consistency. Also, I copied your code EXACTLY and it worked for me. Not sure why it's not working for you :(

Comment: Hey David do we need to add anything in the .ts file for this....I haven't done that?

Comment: I was able to do this through the component file.......Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this through adding some code in the component and displayed the same on the HTML.....Thanks for your help